# Spring AbstractFactoryBean usage

Tags: spring-boot, factory-pattern, spring-annotations, abstract-factory

I want to implement the factory pattern to construct some objects. I'm aware to use `AbstractFactoryBean`, but these objects have initialization parameters provided at runtime.

In fact, I want to refactor code so that users gets created and returned by a `UserFactory` which implements `AbstractFactoryBean`:

```
@Service
public class AuthenticationHandler {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager;
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public void signUp(String email, String password) throws BadCredentialsException {
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .passwordEncoder(rawPassword -> bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(rawPassword))
                .username(email)
                .password(password)
                .authorities("ROLE_USER")
                .build();
        userDetailsManager.createUser(user);
    }
}
```

I'm looking also to configure the factory using Java annotations. Please How to do that!

## Edit: Solution

I finally implemented it as below:

```
@Configuration
class UserConfig {

    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    UserConfig(BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<String, String, UserDetails> userFactory() {
        return this::user;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    UserDetails user(String email, String password) {
        return User.builder()
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder::encode)
                .username(email)
                .password(password)
                .authorities("ROLE_USER")
                .build();
    }
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function<Email, Password, UserDetails> {
    UserDetails apply(Email email, Password password);
}
```

The `signUp()` method become now as:

```
@Service
public class AuthenticationHandler {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager;
    @Autowired
    private Function userFactory;

    public void signUp(String email, String password) throws BadCredentialsException {
        UserDetails user = constructUser(email, password);
        userDetailsManager.createUser(user);
    }

    private UserDetails constructUser(String email, String password) {
        return (User) userFactory.apply(email, password);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you insisting on Abstract Factory? Looks like you have already decided what do you want to use but not aware of path to reach there. Rather, you should start putting OOPS in your code and see where it takes you.

Comment: I just wanted to delegate the user construction responsibility to another class in order to make the signUp() method more cohesive. I found a solution! I'll edit the answer to display it